# Two second order ODEs convert into a system of first order ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$2x_1''=-4x_1+3x_2$$

$$\frac{9}{4}x_2''=-\frac{27}{4}x_2+3x_1$$

I should these two second order ODEs as a system of first order ODEs.
And their coefficient matrix should become $4$ by $4$ matrix.

I can't understand what this sentence means... and how to do it....

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Denote with $v_i=x_i'$, $i=1,2$

Then your equation becomes $2v_1'=-4x_1+3x_2$ and $\frac{9}{4}v_2'=-\frac{27}{4}x_2+3x_1$

Therefore your four equations are
$$ 2v_1'=-4x_1+3x_2$$
$$ \frac{9}{4}v_2'=-\frac{27}{4}x_2+3x_1$$
$$x_1'=v_1$$
$$x_2'=v_2$$

The coefficient matrix is 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 
-2 & \frac{3}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
\frac{4}{3} & -3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$